# Game crashes with error as - > onRealTimeMessageSent(Unknown Source)

Tags: android, andengine, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

Did anyone come across this type of error ?? 
This thing happens after the message is sent succesfully to the other device ..

```
01-30 14:20:38.894: E/AndroidRuntime(6258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 14:20:38.894: E/AndroidRuntime(6258): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 14:20:38.894: E/AndroidRuntime(6258): at com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient$29.onRealTimeMessageSent(Unknown Source)
01-30 14:20:38.894: E/AndroidRuntime(6258): at com.google.android.gms.internal.ex$am.a(Unknown Source)
```

Code i have used to send message to the others participants :

```
for (Participant p : mParticipants)
{
    if (p.getParticipantId().equals(mMyId))
        continue;
    if (p.getStatus() != Participant.STATUS_JOINED)
        continue;

    if(p.isConnectedToRoom()) 
    {   
        getGamesClient().sendReliableRealTimeMessage(null, msgData, mRoomId,p.getParticipantId());
    }          
}
```

Can someone please explain me why is it coming as unknown source ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got it too. It will not happen if you specify a `RealTimeReliableMessageSentListener` in the first parameter of `sendReliableRealTimeMessage`. But updating to a new version of that library does bring annoying surprises :-(

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks .. I didnt actually bother to add listener to it .. because Google themselves havent added a listener in there sample app code ButtonClicker so i was assuming it may not be necessary. :)

Comment: I know, and it was not necessary in the previous version.

Comment: I can't believe I had to make a hotfix due to this. So stupid.